# How to install python packages in a private network

Tags: python, pip, pypi

I'm an experienced programmer, but very new to python. My company requires us to do development on a private network for some of our projects. There is a pypi index on the private network which can be used to install packages using pip. Recently, while needing to install a package, the pypi index when down and was down for several hours. Although it did come back up eventually, the situation begs the question, how do I install packages (maybe manually without pip) in the absense of an index? I've tried to google this, but came up empty. I'm sure there's a way, but I'm probably not searching for the right phrase. Thanks for any help with.

Comment: I'm not sure if I got your problem correctly, but wheel packages can help. https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Comment: @בנימיןכהן I don't think that is necessarily they're asking about. I think @Sanjeev is asking about how to still `pip install` a package when an index goes down

Comment: At the very least, I think answers relating to that would be worth mentioning, which the other post you linked to does not

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+offline+installation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually install Python packages if you have read access to the package repositories. Every Python package has a `setup.py` file in the root directory and you can do something like

```
python setup.py sdist
```

This creates a subdirectory called `dist` which contains a compressed archived file, `tar.gz` or `.zip` depending in your OS. You can pass this archived file to pip and install the package

```
pip3 install some-python-package.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 1):

I would download the wheel and install that. For this to  you do need to install the wheel package:

`pip install wheel`

You can then tell pip to install the project (and it'll download the wheel if available), or the wheel file directly:

```
pip install project_name  # download and install
pip install wheel_file.whl  # directly install the wheel
```

The wheel module is also runnable from the command line and you can use it to install already-downloaded wheels:

```
python -m wheel install wheel_file.whl
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you can get around this issue. The two that I know of are:

1. Use a proxy to get to the standard PyPI. If your company permits it, then you can tunnel your traffic through their proxy and install packages from PyPA's standard locations.
2. Use a locally hosted index. All you need is a directory structured like https://pypi.org/simple/, and you can then `pip install -i ~/my/personal/index/path` and packages will be installed from there.